# An unknown command-line option [/auto] was specified

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-installation, repair-install

When I try to repair install windows from a booted USB drive, I get this error:

[image]

> The upgrade option isn't available if you start your computer using
>   installation media.
>
> If a copy of Windows is already installed on this computer and you
>   want to upgrade, remove the installation media and restart your
>   computer. After Windows has started normally, insert the installation
>   media and run Windows Setup.

And when I try over, I get this error:

> An unknown command-line option [/auto] was specified.

[image]

Comment: If the installation media is already the only partition on the medium you're using, you might have luck just creating a new installation file. How far into the setup do you get before your first error? As soon as you boot from the device or after you've selected some options?

Comment: "If the installation media is already the only partition on the medium you're using, you might have luck just creating a new installation file."
I am not sure if I fully understood that.
"How far into the setup do you get before your first error?"
When i boot over stick, i can chose language, and after pressing "Install" i get the error from first screenshot.
The second error i get right after when I start over troubelshould > terminal with 
"setup.exe /auto upgrade"

Comment: First line just meant that if you're using an external hard/flash drive for your installation media, it needs to be on the front partition if there are multiple. What specific Windows do you currently have and what specific Windows are you trying to install? It sounds like you're trying to go from one version to another. If you're trying to do a clean install you should be able to delete the disk's currently used partitions from the Custom Install interface of your installation media (just don't wipe whatever you're booting from - it'll be labeled as a different drive).

Comment: I tried both copying stick root to C:Temp and starting it from there, or over USB boot stick. How do you mean front partition? I just used Media Creation tool, i guess i have default partioning. I have windows 10 pro, i gues 1903 and i want to make a repair install to same windows 10 because i messed up permissions.https://superuser.com/questions/1447481/reset-windows-10-permissions?noredirect=1#comment2184155_1447481

Comment: If the computer is bootable, boot from the hard disk, then *from Windows* go to the root folder on the USB and start the setup program. The Upgrade option will then be available. Do not copy the USB to `C:\Temp`.

Comment: Hey harrymc :) yeah the problem is i can't see anything. First of all all "system" letters are missing, and when i start the setup.exe i see only the menubar no box with content. I tried also once tried starting via cmd, and blind copying command.Then i get the same unknown command error.